# Oracle simple query with calculation in Case statement

Tags: oracle, case

I have a query that calculates the difference in minutes between two dates.  The problem I have is that the query needs to return a different result based on the number of minutes elapsed.  I would like to do this without recalculating the minutes for every case.  I would like to do this in a simple query if possible.

Ex. I would like to remove the (d2-d1)*1440 and save to a variable so it can be used again in the query.

```
select a, b, c,
(case
when (d2-d1)*1440 < 10 then 'Less than 10'
when (d2-d1)*1440 < 500 then 'Less than 500'
else 'More than 500'
end
)
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of inline query would help to get the desired result

```
select a, b, c,
(case
when ddiff < 10 then 'Less than 10'
when ddiff < 500 then 'Less than 500'
else 'More than 500'
end
)
from (select a,b,c, (d2-d1) * 1440  ddiff  from my_table) X
```

Comment: You are missing the ddiff alias in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery.

```
select a, b, c,
(case
when min_diff < 10 then 'Less than 10'
when min_diff < 500 then 'Less than 500'
else 'More than 500'
end
)
from ( 
    select a,b,c, (d2-d1)*1440 AS min_diff from my_table
)
```